# Access JSONArray by name in javascript

Tags: json

I have an application which returns JSONObject like this:

```
Result:
{
status: "200", 
data: {
exposedItemsList: [
{
type: "process", 
itemID: "25.22982aaf-aff7-4e03-9c7c-a8475bf48354", 
itemReference: "/25.22982aaf-aff7-4e03-9c7c-a8475bf48354", 
processAppID: "2066.18beb803-e14e-4f6f-9d08-a807091aea7e", 
snapshotID: "2064.c0d236be-b5c8-463a-a38d-7267af836918", 
snapshotName: "SP20", 
snapshotCreatedOn: "2012-08-22T09:28:22Z", 
display: "Access Request", }
] 
} 
}
```

I have used below function to get Json:

```
$.get("url of my application", function (data) {
                   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                   ;
               });
```

This works and returns entire JSONObject. However, I want to access "exposedItemsList" JSONArray and elements  within it.
I have tried

```
alert("Data Loaded: " + data.exposedItemsList[0].type);
```

but id did not work...

Pls advise.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this issue by adding

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible answers:

1. data is a string, not an object (in which case you would have to parse/eval it),
2. you must write `data.data.exposedListItems[0].type`, since data contains the topmost object, which has a data field:

   $.get("url of my application", function (result) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + result.data.exposedListItems[0].type);
   });

Comment: Thanks for reply. I could resolve this issue by adding var obj = JSON.parse(data);